# how to delete only some columns value from a table with where caluse

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-delete

Below is my table.

see the `Building_Id` 41. I want to delete all the values from this row except `Building_Id` and `Building_Name`. How can I do that.

[image]

Comment: Don't post images but copy-paste your schema and sample data here. Also show a desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't delete specific values, you can only delete the entire row.**

However, you can `UPDATE` all these value into `null` for this `Building_Id= 41` row:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET SFTI_Id = NULL,
    SPMU_Id = NULL,
    Sanctioned_DPR = NULL,
    Sacnctioned_Contract = NULL
WHERE Building_Id= 41;
```

Assuming the columns accept null values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to delete if you're wanting to leave the row itself intact. You want to update the row, and change the column value.

```
UPDATE <table name>
SET
    SFTI_ID= '',SPMU_ID='',Block_Id='',Sanctioned_DPR='',sanctioned_Contract=''
WHERE
   Building_Id=41
```